# how to fix error with Substring and IndexOf c#

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

i dont know how to fix this runtime error:

http://postimg.org/image/hh9vl7hi9/

The value of roomsInfo is : "@114|mag|nir|1||dan|nir|1||\0"
and it crash when the value is : "dan|nir|1||\0"
(in the second time of the while) when i try to do this line:

```
roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 1, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
```

this is the full code:

```
    String roomsInfo = Program.sendToServ("@10||");
        String[] room_name = new String[100];
        String[] admin_name = new String[100];
        String[] number_of_people = new String[100];
        int check = 0, count = 0;
        if(roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0') > 5)
        {
            roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|')+1, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
            while (roomsInfo[roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 2] != '\0' && roomsInfo[roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 1] != '\0') // @114|roomName1|RoomAdmin1|count1||roomName2|RoomAdmin2|count2||
            {
                if (check == 0)
                {
                    room_name[count] = roomsInfo.Substring(0, roomsInfo.IndexOf('|'));
                    check = 1;
                    roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 1, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
                }
                if (check == 1)
                {
                    admin_name[count] = roomsInfo.Substring(0, roomsInfo.IndexOf('|'));
                    check = 2;
                    roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 1, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
                }
                if (check == 2)
                {
                    number_of_people[count] = roomsInfo.Substring(0, roomsInfo.IndexOf('|'));
                    check = 0;
                    count++;
                    roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 2, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
                }

            }
        }
```

Thank you!
Nir

Comment: You should consider starting with `roomsInfo.Split('|')` instead of `roomsInfo.IndexOf('|')` it will put each part of that string into an array, which should be easier for you to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to Substring Correctly You must Get the length of substring Just like when you get length of Vector in Math.

for example you have two points in one line. say 5 and 13. To get the length between 5 and 13 you must subtract 5 from 13. so `13 - 5 = 8`

```
        int startIndex = roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 1;
        int endIndex = roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0');
        int length = endIndex - startIndex;

        roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(startIndex, length); // Will Get nir|1||
```

If you want to get the Last char too. you must add 1 to length

```
        roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(startIndex, length + 1); // Will Get nir|1||\0
```

From what i see in your code. your Substrings are All wrong. so you must do this to all of them.

One line solution

```
roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') + 1, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0') - roomsInfo.IndexOf('|') - 1);
```

Again if you want to get last char too you must add 1 to the length.

Comment: What you have wrote isnot work because it desappired the /0 (your last row you wrote i put in the start)

Comment: if you add one to the length it will take it. but note that /0 is empty char . so ithink you cannot see it throgh debug @user3346907

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it might be something to do with the || between records (is that a record delimiter, I assume?) and your substring indexing.

What Glenn is saying would work to split a record into fields, but in your case all of your records are chained together and (I assume delimited by || ?) then finally terminated by a null zero. Therefore you would first need to split your string into set of records, before splitting the records into fields.

```
  struct RoomInfo
  {
    public String RoomName;
    public String AdminName;
    public String WhatIsNir;
    public int NumberOfPeople;
  }

  var roomsInfo = new List<RoomInfo>();
  String allData = "@114|mag|nir|1||@115|dan|nir|1||\0".TrimEnd('\0');
  String[] delimiters = new string[] { "||" };
  String[] records = allData.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  foreach (var record in records)
  {
    String[] fields = record.Split('|');
    roomsInfo.Add(new RoomInfo
      {
        RoomName = fields[0],
        AdminName = fields[1],
        WhatIsNir = fields[2],
        NumberOfPeople = int.Parse(fields[3])
      });
  }
```

Another issue might be that your data and your fields are a mismatch. I.e. where do your three fields repeat in the following string? "@114|mag|nir|1||dan|nir|1||\0". I see four fields in that string, so I added one (room name) in the above example.

Of course, to use this solution is to say that there's a commitment to your data format. If this is something you are able to change (i.e. not determined by a 3rd party), then I would change it to something a little more standard. Even a basic form of CSV would be similar, but might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is extremely complex. It can be done with few lines of code, which is easier to maintain:

```
    string roomsInfo = Program.sendToServ("@10||");
    var room_name = new List<string>();
    var admin_name = new List<string>();
    var number_of_people = new List<string>();

    if(roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0') > 5)
    {
        roomsInfo = roomsInfo.Substring(roomsInfo.IndexOf('|')+1, roomsInfo.IndexOf('\0'));
        var records = roomsInfo.Split(new[] {"||"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var rec in records)
        {
            var fields = rec.Split(new [] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            room_name.Add(fields[0]);
            admin_name.Add(fields[1]);
            number_of_people.Add(fields[2]);
        } 
    }
```

This can be improved, of course, in order to control exceptions.